# Creating a time measurement decoration for a recursive function with memoization

Tags: python, recursion, time, decorator

I'm trying to create a decorator to measure the time of a function:

```
def time_dec(func: Callable):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = timer()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(timer()-t1)
    return inner
```

It works for measuring the time of the following function:

```
@time_dec
def fib_rec(n):
    def fibo(n2):
        return n2 if n2 <= 1 else fibo(n2 - 1) + fibo(n2 - 2)
    return fibo(n)
```

But not for the following function:

```
cache = {0: 0, 1: 1}
@time_dec
def fib_mem(n):
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    cache[n] = fib_mem(n - 1) + fib_mem(n - 2)
    return cache[n]
```

For the second function, is returns one measurement for every recursion that is performed. I would like one measurement for the complete function (like it works for the first function).

Comment: What does it do that is not expected?

Answer (score 1):

Your `inner` should return the decorated function result in order to work correctly. Otherwise the function after decorating returns `None`.

```py
def time_dec(func: Callable): 
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = timer()
        result=func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(timer()-t1)
        return result
    return inner
```

The first one works only, because you defined an inner (nested) function inside of it and you the function you decorated was the "outer" one. I'd definitely consider using `perf,_counter` instead of timer and `@wraps` to keep the identity of the function intact.